# Vampire book series about twin sister high schoolers with one being a vampire

Tags: story-identification, books, vampire

I need help remembering the title to a vampire book series I read back in the early 2000s. The details I can remember include twin sisters and at least one of them gets turned into a vampire. There was a scene where one of them was craving blood and ate raw meat. I think they were high schoolers and worked as life guards at a pool or something. I also believe the author was male. 
Hope someone else remembers this.

Comment: After a quick Google search, maybe "My Sister the Vampire" series by Sienna Mercer. However this author is female, the series seems to be for YA or kids. All the titles end with exclamation mark. (ex Twin Spins! or Switched!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [The Blood Coven Vampires](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MRAGYNR) series.  I found your question because I was looking for the same book series it was driving me crazy. The 1st book is called *Boys that Bite* by Mari Mancusi.

> From Book 1: Sunny MacDonald doesn’t know what to expect when she’s dragged to Club Fang by her twin sister Rayne. But when the devastatingly handsome vampire Magnus mistakes her for her goth-loving twin and bites her on the neck, she realizes his fangs are all too real…and all too deadly.
>
> Now Sunny and Magnus find themselves in a race against time to find a way to reverse the transformation before Sunny becomes a vampire forever. Something she definitely doesn’t want—even if does mean spending eternity with a certain brooding boy who bites…

Comment: This would be greatly improved, by removing the partial Amazon screenshot, and quoting, the relevant text. (images of just the book covers would be fine, as would a link to the Amazon page).

Answer (score 1):

Reminds me of Dangerous Girls by R.L Stine who happens to be a male author. Girls go to camp, come back turned and eat raw meat, and one twin tries hard to find a cure and the "restorer", the person who can turn them back to human. The other twin though is a different story, and they're both girls.